# Saving a WolframScript File to the cloud?

Tags: scripting

Is there a way to save the current (or some target) WLS file to the cloud programattically (via `wolframscript`)?

So if we are editing, i.e., `/home/user/file.wls`, how can we save/override a cloud notebook called "File"?

I tried

```
CloudDeploy[NotebookOpen["/home/user/file.wls"], "File"]
```

but get

````
FrontEndObject::notavail: A front end is not available; certain operations require a front end.

```
````

Comment: I think you want `NotebookObject` instead of `NotebookOpen`.  You can also simply go `File`>`Save to Cloud..`

Comment: @kickert: Using `NotebookObject` causes the same error. Also: I'm looking to do this programatically (in a script), so can't use `File > Save >..`.

Comment: `CloudDeploy[
 NotebookObject[
  "D:\\documents\\sample.wls"], "sample.wls"]`

Comment: have you tried `CopyFile` and used a `CloudObject` as the second argument?

Comment: kickert: That worked, except now the `"File"` cloudobject is just raw text in the cloud, and none of its contents are "runnable" like in a normal Wolfram notebook.

Comment: Are you using `CloudGet` or `Import` or `CloudImport` or `CloudEvaluate` or something else?  Lots of nuanced options in the functions when it comes to `CloudObjects`

Comment: kickert: Here is the actual command I've been running: `CopyFile["/home/user/file.wls", CloudObject["file.wls"], 
 OverwriteTarget -> True]`.

Comment: but then what are you using to call it?

Comment: kickert: wolframscript

Comment: `CloudGet` in a notebook? Command line for Wolfram Engine? I am not sure I understand.

Comment: kickert: See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html

Comment: Yes, I am familiar, but I am asking what code or command you are using to call/execute it.

Comment: kickert: I usually use either `wolframscript -file my_file.wl` or `wolframscript -code <code>`.